# Is the person in this "Yellow Peril" NZ cartoon Maori?

Tags: 20th-century, new-zealand

[image: Cartoon being discussed]

In this anti-Asian [1907 NZ cartoon](https://iso.org.nz/2015/07/19/the-poison-of-nationalism/), is the person being entangled by the octopus in this cartoon meant to be Maori?

The clothing and long hair suggest it's not a white New Zealander (pakeha), 
but I assume that more likely than not, people with an anti-Asian prejudice from that time would regard Maoris as inferior to whites. Should I interpret the figure as a metaphorical representation of NZ, one that'd be used even by people who'd be prejudiced against Maoris?

Comment: The picture seems pretty clear; the garbs and what looks to me like facial tattoo are distinctly Maori. Using native imagery as a representation of the country isn't that unusual. See for example the American Indian Head coins.